# brekpoint is not hitting in peace of MFC C++ code in vs2008 deployed in Windows CE emulator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, windows-ce, breakpoints

I tried to debug a piece of mfc C++ code in VS2008 which had deployed in Windows CE emulator.

Got the below instruction while i place a cursor on the breakpoint.

"The breakpoint will not currently be hit, No executable is currently loaded at this location".

Since i am very new to VS2008, Dont know what to do, Searched a lot in google. but not able to solve the issue any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you compiled with symbols?

Comment: i dont know wwhether i compiled with or without symbols , how do we come to know with or without symbols?

Comment: What does your code look like and where is your breakpoint located?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're compiling your code in "Debug" mode instead of "Release"

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the existing EXE on your device and then deploy/debug again.  I've had multiple situations where VS2K8 wouldn't overwrite an older EXE on the device.  When this happens the program starts, but the breakpoints show as white circles instead of red ones.  VS2K8 seems to have a bug where it sometimes doesn't overwrite the existing EXE with the newly compiled one even if it is newer.